# Understanding $n$ Balls into $m$ Boxes

Tags: combinatorics

I have problems understanding the problem of how many different ways are there to put $n$ balls into $m$ boxes?

Suppose Different balls, different boxes. The boxes are allowed to be empty.
In this case we can order the balls by $1,2,3,...$ and the cells by $1, 2, 3,...$. Take ball 1. We can put it in cell $1$ or $2$ or $3 ...$ or $m$. In other words for each ball there are $m$ choices of where to put it. Consequently the total number of ways are $m \times m \times m \times ... \times  m = m^n$

My question is why the total is not $n^m$ since for each box there are $n$ choices of balls?

Thank you

Comment: When you put a ball into a box, you are choosing a box for that ball. Instead, every box may be assigned to more than one ball.

Comment: You might find [this](http://cns-web.bu.edu/~eric/EC500/attachments/ON(2d)LINE(20)READINGS/ballsinboxe.pdf) page helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is understanding why this is the result of multiplication.  Each time you make a choice of box, the next step can occur for any of the possible $m$ first steps.  Imagine actually doing this, first ball by ball, and then doing it over again box by box.

**Going ball by ball:** for the "first" ball you have $m$ choices of box.  Put it in a box.  Now, you only have $n-1$ balls left, but you still have $m$ bins.  You can no longer put that ball anywhere.  So for the "second" ball you can put it in any of the $m$ bins.

**Going box by box:** for the "first" box you have $m$ choices, pick one and put a ball in it.  Now you have $n-1$ balls left but you still have $m$ boxes.  So the "second" box could be the same as the first box.

Think about a simple example with two balls and three boxes.

**Going ball by ball:** place the "first" ball in a box.  Either you put it in box $a,b,$ or $c$.

If you put it in box $a$ you can still put the second ball in box $a,b,$ or $c$.

If you put it in box $b$ you can still put the second ball in box $a,b,$ or $c$.

If you put it in box $c$ you can still put the second ball in box $a,b,$ or $c$.

So your possibilities are $(aa), (ab), (ac), (bb), (ba), (bc), (cc), (ca), (cb)$

**Going box by box:** pick a box, and place a ball in it.

If you pick box $a$ you can still put the second ball in box $a,b,$ or $c$.

If you pick box $b$ you can still put the second ball in box $a,b,$ or $c$.

If you pick box $c$ you can still put the second ball in box $a,b,$ or $c$.

So your possibilities are $(aa), (ab), (ac), (bb), (ba), (bc), (cc), (ca), (cb)$